# Incorrect freezing of weights maskrcnn Tensorflow 2 in object_detection_API

Tags: tensorflow, openvino

I am training the maskrcnn inception v2 model on the Tensorflow version for further work with OpenVino. After training the model, I freeze the model using a script in object_detection_API directory:

**python exporter_main_v2.py \
--trained_checkpoint_dir training 

--output_directory inference_graph 

--pipeline_config_path training/mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_1024x1024_coco17_gpu-8.config**

After this script, I get the saved model and pipeline files, which should be used in OpenVInO in the future
The following error occurs when uploading the received files to model optimizer:

Model Optimizer version:
2020-08-20 11:37:05.425293: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
[ FRAMEWORK ERROR ]  Cannot load input model: TensorFlow cannot read the model file: "C:\Users\Anna\Downloads\inference_graph\inference_graph\saved_model\saved_model.pb" is incorrect TensorFlow model file.
The file should contain one of the following TensorFlow graphs:

1. frozen graph in text or binary format
2. inference graph for freezing with checkpoint (--input_checkpoint) in text or binary format
3. meta graph

Make sure that --input_model_is_text is provided for a model in text format. By default, a model is interpreted in binary format. Framework error details: Error parsing message.
For more information please refer to Model Optimizer FAQ (https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_Model_Optimizer_FAQ.html), question #43.

I teach the model by following the example from the link article, using my own dataset: https://gilberttanner.com/blog/train-a-mask-r-cnn-model-with-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api

On gpu, the model starts and works, but I need to get the converted model for OpenVINO

Answer (score 0):

Run the mo_tf.py script with a path to the SavedModel directory:

python3 mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir <SAVED_MODEL_DIRECTORY>